# @sessionattributes

Tags: spring-mvc

When a controller method redirect to any url, the framework automatically appends all the model attributes in url query string even if those attributes are stored in session.

is there any way to disable that automatic append.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 3.1, you can use `RedirectAttributes` as a parameter in your controller method. When you redirect to another controller the attributes are passed using this object.

Example:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String handle(Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
     if (result.hasErrors()) {
         return "accounts/new";
     }
     // Save account ...
     redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", account.getId()).addFlashAttribute("message", "Account created!");
     return "redirect:/accounts/{id}";
 }
```

Source:

[Spring 3.1 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)